# MouseWheel event not getting captured in MFC VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

Currently i am migrating one of my MFC applications to Windows 10 64 Bit from Windows 7 32 bit. Suddenly my mouse wheel stopped working in my application.

The same code works in the application on windows 7 .

Can anyone please advise ?

```
//Mouse registration
m_MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,&MouseHookProc, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), GetCurrentThreadId());

//Callback function
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CPPUITrace objTrace(_T("CPostProcUIControlsDialog::MouseHookProc"));

    objTrace.LogError(_T("Madhu::Got wParam %d and nCode is %d"),wParam,nCode);

    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL) //Never getting this event
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the hook successfully set?

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, it's missing `return CallNextHookEx(ghook, ncode, wparam, lparam);` Also this may not be the right approach if you are just trying to handle mouse wheel message.

Comment: Why are you using a hook for processing mouse wheel messages? This sounds overly complicated to me. Just process WM_MOUSEWHEEL message normally like any other WM_MOUSExxx message.

Comment: This is a legacy application working fine in Win7,When i migrated it to Win10, it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer myself . In windows 10 there is a new concept of scroll working on active window as well as on ghost windows . Since the code snippet was from legacy previously the event used to be passed to the main window as ghost window was not consuming it .

From windows10 onwards there is a Mouse scroll setting and if it is activated the ghost window also starts consuming the mouse scroll events